# find: missing argument to « -ok »

Tags: shell, find

A while ago, I ran `chmod` to change some file permissions to 777. A friend of mine told me to never `chmod 777`, so I decided to change the permissions again.
So, first I looked for all the 777 files:

```
find ~ -perm 777
```

I get a few files, it's OK.

Then I try to convert them into 755 files:

```
find ~ -perm 777 -ok chmod 755 {}\;
```

And I get this error message:

```
find: missing argument to « -ok »
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need a space between the `{}` and the `\;`.